# Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting?

Tags: magento-1.6, php-5.4

I have created [custom admin module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9966/custom-admin-module-not-showing) it's showing empty page without adding `<stores/>` tag in config.xml file if I adding `<stores/>` tag it's returning an error.

error is:

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting! in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php on line 185
```

//config.xml file

```
<stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <package>
                    <name>default</name>
                </package>
                <theme>
                    <default>Department</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
```

Can you tell my bug where it is?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This error is quite good. It normally means that you implemented some circle, endless recursion or something like that.

After this error you normally get a stack trace where you can see, what functions are called. Have a look, hook into the methods and check why you have a so much nested methods.

Anshu is right, if it is necessary to call a lot of functions, it might help to increase the max_nesting_level.

Comment: And note that this max nesting level is not native to PHP, it's added by xdebug as is the error message. The intent is to prevent endless recursion, which would ultimately result in a memory limit error.

Comment: @Fabian,  
where is xedug config file?

Comment: @davidalger,
where is xedug config file?

Comment: It is called php.ini ;-) http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings

Answer (score 0):

If you have xdebug installed then try to increase xdebug.max_nesting_level in your xedug config file or your php.ini 
http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level

Comment: where is xedug config file?

Comment: If you are using any linux machine, then you can try to find using something like find / -name 'xdebug.so'